# What's wrong with my java code? Project Euler 12

Tags: java

I code in Java for Project Euler (http://projecteuler.net/). I'm fairly new to coding in Java, so I'm only on problem #12, which asks you to find the smallest triangle number (e.g, 1+2+3+4+5) with more than 500 factors. I wrote the code for it, but for some reason my code keeps getting hung:

```
        int factors = 0;
    long triangle = 0L;
    for(int x = 1; factors <= 500; x++){
        triangle += x;
        for(int y = 1; y<=triangle; y++){
            if(triangle%y==0){
                factors = factors + 1;
            }
        }
        if(factors > 500){
            System.out.println(triangle);
        }
        else{
            factors = 0;
        }
    }
```

For the convenience of space, I did not include the class or main. The program has no compile-time errors, but I cannot figure out why it is not producing an answer.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Because I assumed that it would be a very large number. Also, to be added to itself in `triangle += x`, it had to equal something at first.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see how the values of factors, triangle change with each iteration of x?

Comment: It's not getting hung; it's just really inefficient. To solve that problem, you're going to have to try a different approach.

Comment: @DennisMeng that'd be an answer

Comment: @eis Alright, I'll post an answer with more detail.

Comment: Are you sure it is hanging.  You are using a brute force method to calculate factors.  Consider adding some prints to show progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program doesn't actually hang; it's just really inefficient.

Since this is a Project Euler problem, I'm not going to outright give you a more optimized solution. What I will tell you though is that

```
for(int y = 1; y<=triangle; y++){
    if(triangle%y==0){
        factors = factors + 1;
    }
}
```

is the part that needs to be faster. You don't need to actually loop over every number less than `triangle`. If `triangle` is in the millions (as an example), this adds way more computation than is necessary. How might you get the number of factors more quickly?